# Linq: query syntax where operator does not understand predicates of type Expression

Tags: linq, expression-trees, specification-pattern, linq-query-syntax

I have defined a specification as an object of type `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsSystemUser
{
  get
  {
    return user => user.UserID == -1;
  }
}
```

This works marvellously with queries written in extension method syntax:

```
return workspace.GetDataSource<User>().Where(UserSpecifications.IsSystemUser);
```

But not with Linq query syntax:

```
return from user in workspace.GetDataSource<User>() where UserSpecifications.IsSystemUser select user;
```

The compiler gives me `cannot implicitly convert type 'Expression<Func<User, bool>>' to 'bool'`.

What gives? I thought Linq query syntax was just a cute DSL dressing up the extension method syntax. Can anyone tell me how I might use my lovely specifications with Linq query syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query expression is being translated into:

```
return workspace.GetDataSource<User>()
                .Where(user => UserSpecifications.IsSystemUser);
```

The lambda expression is introduced implicitly - but you don't want it in this case. So don't use query expression syntax... Given that here the query expression syntax is *longer* than using the extension methods directly, and introduces more cruft, why would you want it?

Note that you *can* mix and match like this:

```
return from user in workspace.GetDataSource<User>()
                             .Where(UserSpecifications.IsSystemUser)
       where user.Name == "Bob"
       orderby user.ID
       select user;
```

Comment: Thanks again. Obviously the example was simplified for SO. I want to use query syntax because expressing joins otherwise is filth itself. Your hybrid solution works nicely though.

Comment: I can't accept your answer yet. Have SO not made some kind of special exception for you?

Comment: Hmm I cant even compile your example with extensions method syntax. There is no override of Where method that accepts Expression...

Comment: @Mic: There is for `IQueryable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx